# error: conversion from 'QModelIndex' to non-scalar type 'QString'

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5

Noob here :)
I need a some help about my new project. 
I'm getting this error while run my project:

> error: conversion from 'QModelIndex' to non-scalar type 'QString' requested
>          QString str = ui->okullar->selectionModel()->currentIndex().parent().parent();

```
  qDebug() << ui->okullar->selectionModel()->currentIndex().parent().parent();
  QString str = ui->okullar->selectionModel()->currentIndex().parent().parent();

  QRegExp rx("[, ]");// match a comma or a space
  QStringList list = str.split(rx, QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

Actually qDebug (in first line) gives me:

> QModelIndex(0,0,0x137cb798,QStandardItemModel(0x28fdb4) )

All i need is to parse it... And ui->okullar is a qviewtree...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598128/converting-qmodelindex-to-qstring

Comment: What do you actually want to get after parsing that kind of string? And why?

Comment: I need to know clicked item is group or child...

Comment: In QModelIndex() you have row and column can you get to know what you need from them?

Comment: My model has no column.

Comment: "My model has no column" that's impossible.

Comment: My Model contains (1st Group --2nd Groups -- Childs).
All I need is clicked item is child or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can data from model by using `QModelIndex::data`

```
ui->okullar->selectionModel()->currentIndex().parent().parent().data().toString()
```

Comment: ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file ../../../../Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 486

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
The program has unexpectedly finished.

Comment: Before retrieve data check your index is valid. QModelIndex::isValid.